# Doubt on the best low rank approximation of a symmetric tensor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tensor

I have a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, with $k<n$ whose columns $m_i$ are linearly independent.

So we have $M := [m_1|..|m_k]$.

From the columns of $M$ I can define the following matrix
$$
C = \sum_{i=1}^{k}m_i \otimes m_i
$$
that has rank $k$ and the following family of tensors
$$
T_h= \sum_{i=1}^{k}m_i\otimes...\otimes m_i =  \sum_{i=1}^{k}m_i^{\otimes h} 
$$

Let now, for a $l<k$
$$
\tilde{M} = [\tilde{m}_1|..|\tilde{m}_l] \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times l}
$$
be the rank $l$ matrix that minimizes the following distance according to the Frobenius norm:
$$
D(\tilde{M}) = ||C -  \sum_{i=1}^{l}\tilde{m}_i \otimes \tilde{m}_i||_F
$$
I have the impression that if $\tilde{M}$ minimizes $D(\tilde{M})$, then it also minimizes the following distance, for any $h>2$
$$
D_h(\tilde{M}) = ||T_h -  \sum_{i=1}^{l}\tilde{m}_i^{\otimes h}  ||_F
$$
Is that true? There exist any result in this direction?